# What changes are visible to select statements?

Tags: oracle, transactions

Looking at following transactions on same table:

[image]

Which changes T1 SELECTs get?

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle, with default isolation level (Read Committed)

```
T1, first select  -> Does not see any changes
T1, second select -> Does not see any changes by T2
T1, third select  -> Does not see any changes by T3, but sees changes by T2 (phantom read)
T1, forth select  -> Sees all the changes (phantom read)
```

So basically anything committed is visible to T1.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle explicitly supports the READ COMMITTED, which states that a transaction may read only data that has been committed in the database. There are no dirty reads (reads of uncommitted data).

In above scenario, T1 is only SELECT data, T2 manipulates data (update, delete) and T3 insert data. Based on the COMMIT timings in the transactions, deadlock will not happen and below will visible to the T1:

Third SELECT : Changes from T2 will be visible (but not from T3).
Fourth SELECT: Changes from T2 and T3.
Changes not available to other queries (first and second).

Before COMMIT in any transaction, data will not be visible to any other transaction due to Oracle default ISOLATTION Level settings.

Comment: I assume this is same as what I have written.